# Split Name in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have field as full name in my database (salutation first_name  surname ). Salutation is not mandatory. I want to display only surname.   Rest of data needs to be masked.  I know this is possible if through splitting. Can anybody  give me  code for the same

Comment: Have you tried creating 2 formulas to obtain the data like for example : http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=688024

Comment: Please explain what have you tried? where are you struck....

Comment: for example  if my name is Suresh Patil or Mr. Suresh Patil , it should  display as XX XXXXXX Patil or XXXXXX Patil. I am able to mask full name.

Comment: I tried strFirstName := split (surName," ")[1]  which is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
Mid({fullname}, InstrRev({fullname}, ' ') + 1)
```